# Django 1.8 Geojson

Tags: javascript, json, django, geojson

When serializing a model as geojson (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/), how can you pass the primary key through?

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}}, "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties":
```

You would expect there to be a feature id using the models pk, based on the geojson standard, but there isn't. It's not passed through in the object properties either.

I could always hack it by adding another field, that is a duplicate of the PK, but there must be a way of passing it through.

The reason I'm using geojson is because I want to pass coordinates into Google maps api, and if you serialize a PointField as normal json you end up with something like:

```
"location": "SRID=4326;POINT (-0.1468187000000000 51.5052463000000031)"
```

Maps api would expect those coordinates as (51.5052463000000031, -0.1468187000000000). I could get those coordinates into that format with JS though perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used JS to parse the normal json. Messing about with geojson was more trouble that it was worth.

You will have a string like this is your json response:

```
"location": "SRID=4326;POINT (-0.1468187000000000 51.5052463000000031)"
```

So here's what I did:

```
#grab your POINT field json string and save it somehow
var coords = "location": "SRID=4326;POINT (-0.1468187000000000 51.5052463000000031)"
# you'll need this regex
var regex = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g;
# this gets rid of everything before the semi colon ';'
coords = coords.split(";").pop();
# use the regex to return an array of floats
coords = coords.match(regex).map(function(v) { return parseFloat(v); });
# set those floats to your lat long
var latitude = coords[1];
var longitude = coords[0];
# PROFIT!
console.log(latitude, longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on something similar found [Django Rest Framework - GIS](https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis)
and [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) useful for this.

Comment: In the end, I just ended up doing it in Javascript. Just seems odd that the pk is not there, why would you not want it?

Comment: Hey. Can you post how you solved this? I'm still having a horrible time trying to serialize geojson from two models with a manytomany relationship!

Comment: sammy88888888 I've added an answer with the JS i used. Let me know if it doesn't make sense or if you're having trouble accessing the JSON properly and I'll try and help out.